# symfony twig extends: 'only extend if'

Tags: symfony, twig

In twig there is the 'extends' tag, as found here; http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#conditional-inheritance

Now what I wanna do is something along the lines of the following example from that page:

```
{% extends standalone ? "minimum.html" : "base.html" %}
```

But rather than having 2 templates to extend from, I just want to extend from a template if a specific condition is met.

Now I've tried things such as:

```
{% extends boolean ? "template.html.twig" : "" %}
```

and:

```
{% if boolean %}
    {% extends "template.html.twig" %}
{% endif %}
```

but the former gives an error saying it cannot find a template (since "" obviously isnt a valid path), and the latter just doesn't appear to do anything at all (or rather, it loads for a while and ends up not showing anything)

I've tried some other approaches, but couldn't come up with anything, so figured I'd ask here if I might be missing something.

Thanks in advance for any replies :)

EDIT: To sum up my intent; I am wondering if I can tell my template to only extend if a certain condition is met, and otherwise skip the extend step. (if condition then extend else do nothing)

Comment: Create a blank template to extend from nothing?

Comment: As it says "cannot find a template", problem is not in ternary operator but in the template's path. Where are your parent templates located? Here is an explanation about template pathes: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-naming-locations

Comment: The issue is not in a misunderstanding of the functioning of the extends operator or template pathing, I'm just wondering if the case is covered where you can conditionally extend (without using a blank template, cuz that's silly).
There's a few other ways I can solve this but it would require additional templates, and I figured I'd ask if it was really necessary first.
I'll reiterate my intent above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twig files are generated into PHP classes.

The extends tag should be the first tag in the template, as:

- the `{% extends %}` tag will be converted to the PHP `extends` so the child template will inherit from the parent template.
- the `{% if %}` tag is generated as a PHP `if`, inside a method of the template class, so you can't use `{% if %}` to extend some class or not.

Anyway, you can extends a variable coming from your context, so you should put your condition in the controller.

```
if ($boolean) {
  $template = 'hello.twig';
} else {
  $template = 'world.twig';
}
$this->render("MyBundle:MyFeature:child.html.twig", array('template' => $template);
```

And then in `child.html.twig`:

```
{% extends template %}
```

Comment: Though the code sample doesn't cover my case, I can derive from the first part of your reply that the answer to my question is; no, it is not possible to only extend if a condition is met.
I'll accept it, thank you for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

I came with this hack: added empty layout only with content block. Seems to be working :) I can pass variable from controller and page is loaded with or without layout.

```
<!-- base.html.twig -->
<head>
    ...stuff...
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>

<!-- empty.html.twig -->
{% block content %}{% endblock %}

<!-- some_page.html.twig -->
{% extends boolean ? 'base.html.twig' : 'empty.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    Now this is my real content
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I can barely remember anything from back when I posted this question, but it's great you're adding an answer that is closer to the intended result of asking it.
Since I already accepted an answer I won't be changing it, but thank you for posting regardless :)

Answer (score 0):

In pure twig language, it could be something like this :

```
{% if app.request.pathinfo starts with '/react' %}
    {% set extendPath = "::react_base.html.twig" %}
{% else %}
    {% set extendPath = "CoreBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% endif %}
{% extends extendPath %}
```